# Problem when migrating image assets from local deploy to Amazon S3 on Rails App (Spree)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, spree, data-migration

So, on our project we have been using raw local storage for Spree Images, but now we want to migrate to Amazon S3.

I configured the amazon storage properly and it works properly when uploading new images.

Thing is that we want to migrate our images that we have in local storage to Amazon S3.

For this I have checked this rake task that I found on the internet.

https://www.entreprehero.com/activestorage-migrate-from-local-disk-to-amazon-s3/

I tested it and it works, it actually migrates the image assets to S3 instance

Problem now is that the links on the database that redirect to the image don't work anymore.

As I see it, probably it could be fixed by adding changes on the database on the rake task using the Spree Images model, but I am still looking for the best practice for this though, reason why I drop this question here.

Comment: Did you check s3 link expiry time?

Comment: What does "links on the database" mean? Can you give an example? e.g. the code you're running that produces the incorrect link, what the relevant data in the database is for that link, what the incorrect link is, and what you'd expect/want it to be?

Comment: The problem is that when I migrate the images from local storage to S3 when I use the link that redirects to the image does not longer work (I know that probably I have to run something like a script to update the links on the database to redirect to S3 instead of the local storage.

For instance, this is an image from a Vendor, when I use that link that is generated when the image is in the local storage it stops working when I migrate the image to S3 https://ibb.co/DKnmswJ